# How does the `Cloned` iterator adapter work with `Iterator<T>`?

Tags: rust

Why does the following code work when `Cloned` expects a `DoubleEndedIterator<Item=&'a T>` but `iter()` returns an `Iterator<T>` (instead of an `Iterator<&T>` as it expects)?

```
use std::clone::Clone;
use std::iter::{Rev, Cloned};
use std::fmt::Debug;

fn reversed<'a, U, T>(iter: U) -> Rev<Cloned<U>>
    where U: DoubleEndedIterator<Item=&'a T>,
          T: 'a + Clone + Debug
{
    iter.cloned().rev()
}

fn main() {
    let v0 = (0..10).collect::<Vec<u32>>();
    let mut v0r = v0.clone();
    v0r.reverse();

    assert_eq!(v0r, reversed(v0.iter()).collect::<Vec<_>>());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`T` is generic parameter, and it has a scope in which it applies. Specifically, the `T` parameter for [`std::slice::Iter`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.Iter.html) is **different** from the `T` declared on `reversed`. If this were not the case, I think that it would basically be impossible for humans to ever use generics. It would be like if every variable called `name` referred to the same thing!

> but `iter()` returns an `Iterator<T>`

This isn't true; you can't currently return a trait. You can only return a type that **implements** a trait. Additionally, `std::slice::Iter<T>` implements `Iterator` by returning references to `T`:

```
impl<'a, T> Iterator for Iter<'a, T> {
    type Item = &'a T
 }
```

Comment: "Specifically, the T parameter for std::slice::Iter is different from the T declared on reversed"

This is probably true in the general case when there is no link between the two but I was under the impression that saying `Item=&'a T` in `DoubleEndedIterator<Item=&'a T>` linked these separate `T`s.

Anyway thanks for your response, the second part answers my question.